# Adding a .war file to a Docker image and creating a new image for deployment...FAIL

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

**Summary**:

- I have pulled a Tomcat image, and managed to add a `.war` file to its usr/local/webapps directory.  This new entity is a container, and when I run it locally, it works famously on localhost.  I am able to see the `.war` in the webapps directory.

I want to make this a stand-alone, deplyoment ready entity, which, I gather, means I need to turn it into an image in its own right, so I do this:

- `docker commit theContainer newImage` to make new image.
- `docker run -p 8080:8080 newImage` to run new image.
- `lsof -i :8080` to verify port mapping.

...and see that indeed there is a process listening on the port.  So far so good.

Next, I want to verify that newImage contains the `.war` file, so, with it running, I run:

- `docker exec -it newImage /bin/bash`
- `cd webapps`
- `ls`

...and am happy to find that I can see and navigate the file system of newImage.  Unfortunately, `usr/local/webapps` is empty.

And of course, opening localhost:8080 (and trying all expected servlets) in a browser yields

> **HTTP Status 404 – Not Found** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to
> disclose that one exists.

So the newImage runs but the app is missing.  I have done this, stubbornly, a dozen times, checking all the steps along the way, with no improvement.  Clearly I am missing some key information.

I also, after much searching, cooked up a Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file as follows:

> FROM tomcat:latest
>
> ADD target/theApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
>
> EXPOSE 8080
>
> CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

> version: '3'
>
> ```
> services:
>
>   app:
>
>     build: .
>
>     image: newImage
>
>     ports:
>
>       - 8080:8080
> ```

Again, when I run newImage locally it works a treat, but when I try to push it to Docker  Hub, and then pull it to test it, if fails and lo, it is lacking the .war file that was copied into it.

Am therefore seeking (and thanking in advance for) any insight into the esoterica of docker and the nature of my ignorance.

It currently makes no sense to me that I can successfully modify an image but on running `docker commit` the mod is lost. Somewhere I read that commit does not persist data but I'm not sure that applies to a `.war` file.

Docker Version: 19.03.12

OS: macOS HighSierra 10:13:6

Project: `https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/deploying-a-web-app-into-an-app-server-container.html`

Disclaimer: **Noob**.

Thank you, geeksters.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

ran `docker-compose up` on docker-compose and Dockerfile above, theContainer was built.

ran `docker commit theContainer newImage:latest`  the only difference was adding :latest.

ran newImage, checked for files (present), pushed to Docker Hub, pulled and tested and it's all good.

Check out the image if curious: `docker pull manningpart4/tomcat_test:latest` (be sure to map port ie: 'docker run -p [Your Port]:8080 tomcat_test:latest')